# Battery problem not charging but detected charger(pending-charge state)

Tags: 22.04, dell, power-management, battery

I am using ubuntu 22.04 LTS. Battery charging percentage is showing 21% still when I am connecting with charger it is not showing charging instead of that it's showing not charging. Here is the output of **upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0**

```
  native-path:          BAT0
  vendor:               LGC-LGC3.0
  model:                DELL 49VTP
  serial:               374
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              বুধবার 21 জুন 2023 02:42:09 অপরাহ্ণ (2 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               pending-charge
    warning-level:       none
    energy:              10.212 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         48.1185 Wh
    energy-full-design:  48.84 Wh
    energy-rate:         4.9173 W
    voltage:             10.6 V
    charge-cycles:       N/A
    percentage:          21%
    capacity:            98.5227%
    technology:          lithium-ion
    icon-name:          'battery-low-charging-symbolic'
  History (rate):
    1687336929  4.917   pending-charge
```